# Errors during installing new Laravel application in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install new laravel app on my machine but i am getting errors during installation.I am attaching the image files that shows the errors that i am getting. I am using ubuntu 14.04

[image: Errors during instalation]

Comment: It seems like you're missing some extensions, install them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my typical list of "extras" for a ubuntu install. Your requirements may differ:

```
apt-get install -y fish
apt-get install -y zip
apt-get install -y sqlite
apt-get install -y php-mbstring
apt-get install -y php-curl
apt-get install -y php-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing requirement `php5.6-mbstring`.

It has already been answered over here but for php7.0:

> https://askubuntu.com/a/731380/588546

You could install it using the `apt get` method.

If you are using php5 use:

```
apt-get install php5-mbstring
```

If you are using php5.6 (as i could see you are using it) use:

```
apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
```

If you are using php7.0 use:

```
apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

There might be some other missing dependencies too.

Hope it helps.